# Python update variable levels

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a categorical variable: df['reason'] with 5 levels (0-4) and I want to group level 1 and level 3 to a new level called 'water' and level 2 and level 4 to 'Non-water' and leave level 0 alone. So I want to reduce it from 5 to 3 levels in python. I used a for loop, but it did not return the correct result. Thanks for your input.

```
for i in df['reason']:
    if i==0:
        df['reason']='Not failed'
    elif i in [1,3]:
        df['reason']='Water'
    else:  
        df['reason']='Non-water'
```

Comment: please share what you have done, code, then we will be able to help you.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
level_map = {'level1': 'water', 'level3': 'water',
             'level2': 'Non-water', 'level4': 'Non-water', 
             'level5': 'level5'}

df['new_level'] = df['level'].apply(lambda x: level_map[x])
```